# Running program in Windows service and get "Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))"

Tags: c#, windows

I create a program, which launches another program through COM registry. The main routine looks like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
start.FileName = @"E:\Main\Debug\Executive.exe";
start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
start.CreateNoWindow = true;
start.Arguments = "/run " + arguments[0];
using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))...
```

`Executive.exe` will launch another program by looking through the registry. If I run this routine inside `VS2013` or through command line, all is ok. But if I put this in the `protected override void OnStart(string[] args)` method of a Sindows service. I will get the `Class not registered` error. Any suggestion where I should look at? The main goal is to run `Executive.exe` as Windows service.

Answer (score -1):

We've had luck in the past using the regsvr32.exe Windows command line utility to register the dlls when we ran into that problem. More info on it can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx).